# python: tokenize list of tuples without for loop

Tags: python, tuples, nltk, list-comprehension, tokenize

I have got a list of 2 million tuples with the first element being text and the second an integer. e.g.

```
list_of_tuples = [('here is some text', 1), ('this is more text', 5), ('a final tuple', 12)]
```

I would like to tokenize the first item in each tuple and attach all of the lists of words to a flattened list so the desired output would be.

```
list_of_tokenized_tuples = [(['here', 'is', 'some', 'text'], 1), (['this', 'is', 'more', 'text'], 5), (['a', 'final', 'tuple'], 12)]
list_of_all_words = ['here', 'is', 'some', 'text', 'this', 'is', 'more', 'text', 'a', 'final', 'tuple']
```

So far, I believe that I have found a way to achieve this with a for loop however due to the length of the list, it's really time intensive. Is there any way that I can tokenize the first item in the tuples and/or flatten the list of all words in  a way that doesn't involve loops?

```
list_of_tokenized_tuples = []
list_of_all_words = []

for text, num in list_of_tuples:
    tokenized_text = list(word_tokenize(text))
    tokenized_tuples = (tokenized_text, num)
    list_of_all_words.append(tokenized_text)
    list_of_tokenized_tuples.append(tokenized_tuples)

list_of_all_words = [val for sublist in list_of_all_words for val in sublist]
```

Comment: For starters, you can simply do `list_of_all_words.extend(tokenized_text)` as opposed to `list_of_all_words.append(tokenized_text)` and then flattening at the end. Anyway, how do you expect to do this without looping over `list_of_tuples` in some way or another?

Comment: Your problem isn't the looping itself. Looping over a list with 2 million elements takes essentially no time at all, (about 46.4 milliseconds on my machine). Tokenizing text is an intensive process, and if you are starting with raw text, you don't really have a choice. Perhaps doing it all in bulk will be faster, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools` you could write it as:

```
from itertools import chain, imap

chain.from_iterable(imap(lambda (text,_): word_tokenize(text), list_of_tuples))
```

Testing this:

```
from itertools import chain, imap

def word_tokenize(text):
    return text.split() # insert your tokenizer here

ts = [('here is some text', 1), ('this is more text', 5), ('a final tuple', 12)]

print list( chain.from_iterable(imap(lambda (t,_): word_tokenize(t), ts)) )
```

Output

```
['here', 'is', 'some', 'text', 'this', 'is', 'more', 'text', 'a', 'final', 'tuple']
```

I'm not sure what this buys you though as there are for loops in the implementation of the itertools functions.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> list_of_tuples = [('here is some text', 1), ('this is more text', 5), ('a final tuple', 12)]

# Split up your list(str) from the int
>>> texts, nums = zip(*list_of_tuples)

# Go into each string and split by whitespaces,
# Then flatten the list of list of str to list of str
>>> list_of_all_words = list(chain(*map(str.split, texts)))

>>> list_of_all_words
['here', 'is', 'some', 'text', 'this', 'is', 'more', 'text', 'a', 'final', 'tuple']
```

If you need to use `word_tokenize`, then:

```
list_of_all_words = list(chain(*map(word_tokenize, texts)))
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote this generator for you. If you want to create a list, there isn't much else you can do (except a list comprehension). With that in mind, please see below, it gives you your desired output but joined within a tuple as two seperate lists. I doubt that matters too much and I'm sure you could always change it a bit to suit your needs or preferences.

```
import timeit, random


list_of_tuples = [('here is some text', 1), ('this is more text', 5), ('a final tuple', 12)]
big_list = [random.choice(list_of_tuples) for x in range(1000)]


def gen(lot=big_list, m='tokenize'):
    list_all_words = []
    tokenised_words = []
    i1 = 0
    i2 = 0
    i3 = 0
    lol1 = len(lot)
    while i1 < lol1:
        # yield lot[i1]
        lol2 = len(lot[i1])
        while i2 < lol2:
            if type(lot[i1][i2]) == str:
                list_all_words.append((lot[i1][i2].split(), i1 + 1))
            i2 += 1
        i1 += 1
        i2 = 0
    # print(list_all_words)
    lol3 = len(list_all_words)
    while i3 < lol3:
        tokenised_words += list_all_words[i3][0]
        i3 += 1
    if m == 'list':
        yield list_all_words
    if m == 'tokenize':
        yield tokenised_words


for x in gen():
    print(x)


print(timeit.timeit(gen))
# Output of timeit: 0.2610903770813007
# This should be unnoticable on system resources I would have thought.
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this generator over the OPs approach?

Comment: I think you already know the answer. As does he. He said it must not contain a for loop. The only other away, save from list comp. would be a generator expression. Essentially mapping out the iterator ahead of time and not holding them in memory. This is much more suitable for larger data sets, which I imagine is more likely the case in this example.